# Is there any way to use read.fortran() to read a string rather than file?

Tags: r

So my problem is the following, I am reading through a text file using readlines, and have to go line by line until there is a trigger, and then I have to read the following line using read.fortran().

The problem is that read.fortran() only read text files, and I need to read a line (a string). At the moment I have solved this problem with a disastrous function which writes a file and then I read the file.

```
read.fortran.string <- function(x_string, x_format, x_file, col.names){
# Disastrous function to be changed
  if (missing(x_file)){
    x_file = r'(C:\Users\your_user\Documents\tempfolder\line.txt)'
  }
  write(x_string,x_file)
  
  df = read.fortran(x_file, x_format)
  if (!missing(col.names)){
    colnames(df) <-col.names
  }
  return(df)
}
```

I was expecting that someone will point to a different solution in which:

- Do not require to hardcode a path
- Do not require having to have writing permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that

```r
read.fortran(textConnection(x_string), x_format)
```

will do what you want (untested!)